# How do I configure ESLint to add line spacing between my path aliases?

Tags: typescript, react-native, eslintrc

Right now with my ESLint auto import sorter and ESLint configuration, everything works fine. But I want to add line spacing between my different aliases. Not sure how I can accomplish that.

Right now React imports go on top and all others are grouped together with a space between.

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native-community',
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'import'],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
      rules: {
        'no-undef': 'off',
        'no-shadow': 'off',
        'react/jsx-uses-react': 'off',
        'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-shadow': ['error'],
        'sort-imports': [
          'error',
          { ignoreCase: true, ignoreDeclarationSort: true },
        ],
        'import/order': [
          'error',
          {
            groups: [
              ['external', 'builtin'],
              'internal',
              ['sibling', 'parent'],
              'index',
            ],
            pathGroups: [
              {
                pattern: '@(react|react-native)',
                group: 'external',
                position: 'before',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@tests/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@assets/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@components/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@config/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@constants/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@hooks/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@jotai/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@navigation/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@routes/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@screens/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@theme/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@types/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
              {
                pattern: '@utils/**',
                group: 'internal',
              },
            ],
            pathGroupsExcludedImportTypes: ['internal', 'react'],
            'newlines-between': 'always',
            alphabetize: {
              order: 'asc',
              caseInsensitive: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@tests/*": ["src/__tests__/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@config/*": ["src/config/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"],
      "@jotai/*": ["src/jotai/*"],
      "@navigation/*": ["src/navigation/*"],
      "@routes/*": ["src/routes/*"],
      "@screens/*": ["src/screens/*"],
      "@theme/*": ["src/theme/*"],
      "@app/types/*": ["src/types/*"],
      "@app/utils/*": ["src/utils/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

How it currently looks, but want more spacing between the different aliases.
Thank you and Merry Christmas!

[image]

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/newline-after-import.md? I wonder how well it works with `import/order`.

Comment: There's a prettier plugin that does this https://github.com/trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports, but you may have duplicate config bits. I don't think `import` does it.

Comment: Hey @OFRBG, this helped me accomplish my goal! If you want to make a comment with your answer and I'll go ahead and mark it as the answer.